# Sometimes it's call the didFinishLaunching after close the app

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I have an applications that uses MarketingCloudSDK and we have note that when the app closes, sometimes, after close the app, the function didFinishLaunching from AppDelegate is called, launching the app in background and it makes issues in the app flow.

To proof this, we commented all the code that uses the MarketingCloudSDK and we saw that the problem disappear. I don't know what the sdk does behind to call to the didFinishLaunching function sometimes.

Can you help me?

Kind regards

Comment: Please open a support case as the team may want to collect more details from you. We have no other reports of this across thousands of customers.

Comment: What are your steps to reproduce this?

1. Launch the app, 2. {fill in the blank}, 3. Background the App or Swipe to Kill the App or doesn't matter which? ... help us out here.

Comment: "after close the app" ... how long after? Immediately after? Randomly in the future? Do you have geofence messaging turned on? Are you using InApp Messaging? ... more detail in your question please.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I close the app after opening it, I can either close the app after loading the home view or use the app and close it afterwards. When I swipe to close the app, the function didFinishLaunching it is immediately called.
No, we do not use geofencing messages or in-app messages